# How to rename a downloaded file from within the WinSCP script?

Tags: batch-file, ssis, sftp, winscp

I have WinSCP script that downloads a file from the SFTP server to the local machine. How can I rename the file from within the WinSCP script?

The script is being run from Windows machine.

The WinSCP script:

```
option batch off 
option confirm off 
open sftp://username:password@servername -hostkey=""
option transfer binary
get -latest "oldname.csv" c:\localfolder 
mv c:\localfolder\oldname.csv latestname.csv
exit
```

I tried renaming using the commands:

```
rename InitialFileName FinalFileName
```

then tried using:

```
mv InitialFileName FinalFileName
```

But the script is throwing the error:

```
File not found, Language: en
```

Tried stuff from this [blog](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25738)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to download the file to a different name, specify the new name directly in the [`get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get):

```
get "oldname.csv" c:\localfolder\latestname.csv
```

---

*(Note that when downloading one specific file, the `-latest` switch is pointless. The latest file out of one file[s] is that one file.)*